# QlikView WHERE condition in chart calculated dimension

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a chart with a calculated dimension

it contains 4 possible values A, B, C, or D

however in my bar chart i only want it to contain B and C

I have tried:

```
=MATCH(CATEGORY, 'B','C',)
```

But this just numbers them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `IF` condition this can be achieved with:

```
if(MATCH(CATEGORY, 'B','C'),CATEGORY)
```

Comment: Its information that helped me so I want it to be helpful to everyone on Stackoverflow